# How to import a excel file to the h2 database?

Tags: excel, export, h2

I have an excel sheet with data stored in ten columns and a large number of rows.
I would like to import the content of the file in an H2 database. 
what is the procedure for this?
can I import the excel file as a whole or do I have to write some specific code to handle the content row by row ?

Answer (score 7):

Export your file to CSV and then use the H2 function to read CSV file.

This is described in the [H2 documentation](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#csv).

Answer (score -1):

Just recently I release a library that does this for you.
It inspects the XLS and for every sheet will create a table as a H2 database.

it pushes a download to your browser which is the H2 database zipped up.

You can find the tool here http://ete.straight.io

Hope it helps. Cheers

Comment: The links is broken :'(