# Import .xls/.xlsx Excel files into H2 Database

Tags: sql, excel, h2

Is there any way to import xls/.xlsx Excel files into H2 Database without using any external/third party software?

I know we can import .csv files into H2 but I have a .xlsx file with multiple sheets present on it.

Comment: microsoft ACE OLEDB

Comment: "*without using any external/third party software*" - no

Comment: this question already avilable in StackOverflow Link :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075803/how-to-import-a-excel-file-to-the-h2-database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a excel file to the h2 database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075803/how-to-import-a-excel-file-to-the-h2-database)